# Наложение одного блока на другой

Tags: html, css

Должно получится вот так(фото ниже), но с другими картинками и текстом.

Я взял картинки, сделал им прозрачный фон и сделал их под свой размер. Но как их выставить красиво и самое главное просто, я не понимаю. Конечно если помучиться я могу что-то придумать, но это будет абсолютно нелогично читаемый код.

Заранее спасибо за ответ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.zakrep {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fcdb03;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
}

.container {
  width: 1150px;
  height: 800px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-image: url('/magazine/img/1.png');
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 44px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.banner {
  width: 1035px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-image: url('https://oir.mobi/uploads/posts/2021-03/1616549210_37-p-fon-sinii-gradient-39.jpg');
  margin-left: 60px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.banner2 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner3 {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  height: 400px;
  bottom: 402px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  left: 52px;
}
```

```html
<div class="zakrep">Безкоштовна доставка на сумму від 400 грн</div><br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <li><a href="$">Нове</a></li>
      <li><a href="$">Для чоловіків</a></li>
      <li><a href="$">Для жінок</a></li>
      <li><a href="$">Бренди</a></li>
      <li><a href="$">Sale</a></li>
      <input type="search" placeholder="Пошук по сайту">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="banner2"><img src="/magazine/img/2.jpg" alt="r"></div>
    <div class="banner3"><img src="/magazine/img/3.png" alt="re"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну ты ведь вчера задавал этот вопрос. Ничего особо там не прокомментировал и снова создал вопрос.

Comment: Ваш ответ мне абсолютно не помог, извините конечно но это сложно назвать внятным ответом.
Текст по центру поставить не получается, картинки живут абсолютно своей жизнью, мне хотелось бы внятно и просто.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно получше изучить позиционирование, а так же флексбоксы и/или гриды.
Тогда вопросов не возникнет.
Примерный код вашего макета:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-section {
  position: relative;
  background: dodgerblue;
  min-height: 450px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header-section--titles {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3,
h1,
h5 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: lime;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.decorations {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.decoration-image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 250px;
  top: calc(50% - 125px);
}

.decoration-image > img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.decoration-image--right {
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<div class="header-section">
  <div class="decorations">
    <div class="decoration-image decoration-image--left">
      <img src="https://pngimage.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/ted-png-3.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="decoration-image decoration-image--right">
      <img src="https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/rick-and-morty-png/rick-and-morty-rick-sanchez-battles-wiki-fandom-powered-wikia-25.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-section--titles">
    <h3>Интернет магазин</h3>
    <h1>Kidsworld</h1>
    <h5>Алкоголь, наркотики, книги заклинаний</h5>
    <button>Поехали</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/position
https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/